# Win2016 Server - configure different RDP port on each IP address

Tags: windows-server-2016, rdp

I've a Windows Server 2016 configured with two adapter with different IP address, one for front (user), one for back (admin).

Actually, they use the same RDP port (ie:99999) on each adapter.

I need to configure front card on the 3389 port and admin on 99999.

I've found how to change RDP port in reedit.
I've also found how to force RDP port on one or another IP in firewall advanced manager.

I don't find how to add a second RDP port for the second adapter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure different listening ports for the same RDP service (like in "per Adapter").

You can change that listening port on by modifying the registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
```

Find `PortNumber` and modify it.

If you want to use different ports on the same machine, you will have to use an external service, like NAT.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i will find another solution...